# Calendar in android and add days to array

Tags: android

I want to get all dates from current month and add them to List. I want to add them as String: Sun, 1 Dec. Only what I got is Calendar object with current day. How can I do that? This is any function in Calendar to parse int day on string Monday or somethig? And how add all days in this specific way?
This is what I got on this moment:

```
int day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int daysInMonth = Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        for(int i = 0; i < daysInMonth; i++){
            //here I want to add strings, but don't know how 
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***You need to use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to get date as desired String and add to List. And then move date to next day.***

Look into below code

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int daysInMonth = mCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

ArrayList<String> allDays = new ArrayList<String>();
SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM", Locale.US);
for(int i = 0; i < daysInMonth; i++){
    // Add day to list
    allDays.add(mFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime()));
    // Move next day
    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

This method adds all days of month into list, but in many cases this will add date of next month too. If you don't want this, then see below method.

---

*And if you want to add only remaining days from today (given day) then use below code*

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
// Calculate remaining days in month
int remainingDay = mCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1;
ArrayList<String> allDays = new ArrayList<String>();
SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM", Locale.US);
for(int i = 0; i < remainingDay; i++){
    // Add day to list
    allDays.add(mFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime()));
    // Move next day
    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

This will return `[Fri, 27 Dec, Sat, 28 Dec, Sun, 29 Dec, Mon, 30 Dec, Tue, 31 Dec]` only (As today is 27th Dec 2013). So I think you are looking for this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
         SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy",Locale.getDefault());
         result = dateFormat.format(Calener.getInstance().getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
}
```

result will be 27 Dec 2013